# How can I add a horizontal scrollbar in the google sheet similar to form control scrollbar in excel?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scrollbar

I would like to add a horizontal scrollbar that will provide the values 0-365 based on its position and use this value for calculation.

I am creating a Gantt chart, the same as is on the page https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-gantt-chart.html

There is a horizontal scrollbar that helps "to move" with the calendar.

I have put there a number that I must change manually. I haven't found any solution on the internet.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of control is simply not available natively within Google Sheets. I found a recent response from the [Google Support Forums](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3391478) to indicate this is still the case.

If you want to build this functionality out yourself, it is actually now possible to do so, by taking full advantage of the [Apps Script platform](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces) and their [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) and [HTML Service scripting APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). You can create a dialog box with HTML and JS, which can have any inputs you want, including range sliders, and it can send the values back to the Google Sheet script, which can then save it to a cell. I put together a barebones test to make sure it would work, and it does:

[image: GIF Demo]

I used `Menu -> Tools -> Script Editor`, and then created these two files:

Code.gs:

```
// Trigger dialog to be added to menu on file open
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function saveSliderVal(updatedVal){
  var sheetToSaveTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Gantt');
  if (!sheetToSaveTo){
    sheetToSaveTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  }
  var cellToSaveTo = sheetToSaveTo.getRange('A1:A1');
  cellToSaveTo.setValue(updatedVal);
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function update() {
            document.getElementById('val').innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
        }
        function save() {
            // Call sheet function
            google.script.run.saveSliderVal(parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10));
        }
    </script>
    <input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="365" onchange="update()" oninput="update()" value="0"
        step="1" />&nbsp<span id="val">0</span>
    <br />
    <button id="save" onclick="save()">Save to Gantt</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then reload the sheet after saving your script, and you should see `Dialog -> Open` as a new menu item. Clicking it will bring up your custom HTML.

Comment: I have created both files and the Menu -> Dialog did not appear. Does it depend on another variable as sheet name/list name that I should change as well or should I adjust the code based on names of my items? Have you tried it on a new worksheet without any changes and does it work?

Comment: My bad - looks like I didn't grab all the code when I pasted it here - sorry! I've updated my answer - if you copy my Code.gs and paste it to yours again, and then open & close the spreadsheet, you should get an authorization prompt and then the menu option should appear. Tested on a blank document just to be sure.

Comment: Excellent answer and great to include the working demo!